# Show $C:=\{x\in V:\|x\|\leq 1\}$ is convex

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $(V,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed vector spcae and put $C:=\{x\in V:\|x\|\leq 1\}$. Show that $C$ is convex, which means that $0\leq t\leq 1$ $x,y\in C \Rightarrow tx+(1-t)y \in C$

My attempt:

$\|tx+(1-t)y\|\leq |t| \|x\|+|1-t| \|y\| \leq |t|+|1-t| =1$

Would this be sufficient?

Comment: As $t,1-t \ge 0$, you don't need to use $\vert \cdot \vert$ which complexifies the stuff uselessly.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net okay, thanks for mentioning that

Comment: I might write the final proof like this. Suppose that $x, y \in C$ and $0 \leq t \leq 1$. Then $\|tx + (1-t) y \| \leq \| tx \| + \|(1-t) y \| = t \|x\| + (1-t) \| y \| \leq t \cdot 1 + (1 - t) \cdot 1 = 1$. Thus, $tx + (1 - t)y \in C$. This shows that $C$ is convex.

Comment: @littleO cheers, that's exactly how i wrote it in final form!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you should say that you assume that $x,y \in C$ and $0 \leq t \leq 1$. Other than that, this is correct.